# Folder Library/StartUpItems is empty in OSX 10.8.2

Tags: macos, osx-lion

In System

> Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items

I can see all of the items that i´ve selected to launch at startup, but the folder:

> Library/StartUpItems

is empty??????

Where can i see these items?

Thanks for all.

Best regards!

Comment: Needs migration to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: StartupItems has been deprecated. You should now use Launch daemons and agents: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html

Comment: Where could i see it?